# Looking for an analytical function with f(n) = 1 with x=1 and f(n)=a otherwise.

Tags: real-analysis, graph-theory, constraints, constraint-programming

I am looking for a analytical function that applies to the constraints:
\begin{equation}f(x) = \begin{cases}1 \text{ if } x=1 \\ \alpha \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}, \text{where } 0 \leq \alpha \leq 1 \text{ and } x\in\mathbb{N} \text{ with } x \geq 1\end{equation}
I've been trying to figure this out with the help of WolframAlpha and all the Maths-Knowledge I have, but can't get there.

Links to already existing answers I couldn't find appreciated too.

Comment: Why is this tagged as graph-theory?

Comment: Because I am trying to solve a graph theory problem with this, and thought someone might have seen something similar.

Comment: I see, thank you

Answer (score 2):

How about
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}\alpha+(\alpha-1){\sin\pi x\over \pi (x-1)}&,\quad x\ne 1\\1&,\quad x=1\end{cases}
$$?

Comment: This is not an analytical function, or am I mistaken about the definition here?

Comment: It is analytical since the since function is. You can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function for more information.

Comment: Using L^Hotital's rule we can write $$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)=\alpha+(\alpha-1)\lim_{x\to 1}{\pi\cos \pi x\over \pi}=\alpha+1-\alpha=1$$